# Trying to use inputs for the script to divide and show the answer

Tags: java, input, decimal, division

What I am trying to do it take inputs from a user and have the code divide the two inputs, listing any numbers that need it as a decimal when it doesn't divide into a nice even number. 
So this is what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    float number1; //first number to divide
    float number2; //second number to divide
    float dividend; //product of division

    System.out.print("Enter first integer: "); //prompt
    number1 = input.nextInt(); // read first number 

    System.out.print("Enter second integer: "); //prompt
    number2 = input.nextInt(); // read second number

    dividend = number1 / number2;

    System.out.printf("%d%s%d%s%d.%n", number1, " divided by ", number2, " is ", dividend); 



}
```

This is literally my first day coding, so I expect it will be something simple. I've found through some searching that using integers won't report decimals, so I changed my numbers to floats. When I had all my numbers as integers, it would spit out a number, but wouldn't keep the remainder so I would just get an even number. So I changed them to floats and now it's just giving me an error. I hate to be 'that guy', but does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use scanner.nextFloat() instead of scanner.nextInt();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Scanner.nextFloat()` rather than `Scanner.nextInt()`.

```
System.out.print("Enter first integer: "); //prompt
number1 = input.nextFloat(); // read first number 

System.out.print("Enter second integer: "); //prompt
number2 = input.nextFloat(); // read second number
```

`Scanner.nextFloat()` method scans the next token of the input as a float,

**EDIT**

this solves your other problem:

> Exception in thread "main" java.utilIllegalFormatConversionException:
>   d != java.langlFloat at
>   java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)

```
System.out.printf("%f%s%f%s%f.%n", number1, " divided by ", number2, " is ", dividend);
```

use `f` for float types.

`d` represents a decimal integer.

[**Formatting Numeric Print Output**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: So I did overlook that, but it doesn't seem to fix my problem. `Exception in thread "main" java.utilIllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.langlFloat at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)`. Among other lines that start with `at`.

Comment: @oh i see another problem, i shall solve that give me a second.

Comment: You sir, are fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanBright see the link i've appended for further reading. Also, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Because you changed from using `ints` to `floats`, you also have to change it so that your scanner is taking a `float` input and not an `int` input. Otherwise, you will get an error for mismatching types. To do that, change the following lines:

```
number1 = input.nextInt();
number2 = input.nextInt();
```

to

```
number1 = input.nextFloat();
number2 = input.nextFloat();
```